# Backup a Samsung phone before switching to Nexus?

Tags: backup, nexus-5, data-recovery

I used to backup my phone through Kies. Now I'm switching to Nexus5, and I guess Kies won't work anymore to get my stuff back to phone. What should I do?

Also, I know that some data is automatically stored by Google and associated with my account, so as soon as I login with my new phone it should get it back to me. What is this data?

I could also backup my files by hand, but I would like not to lose apps and app data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many application backup programs available in PlayStore.

- A very light weight application - [Super Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts&hl=en)
- [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)
- If you are rooted then - [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en)

Plus the data stored by google will be automatically retrieved by google once you login to nexus.

Comment: what is this data about? A list of application (to be downloaded again from the store) and their internal data, like settings?

Comment: The data is the list of application and the settings, like WiFi passwords, your mobile data network settings, personal dictionary etc. But the applicaiton data will not be restored. If the app has cloud back up then once you login with G+ or facebook account it will sync the data. For example candy crush, it will retireve the saved levels once you log in with facebook